# Save files to be deleted by rsync on a directory

Tags: rsync, backup

I have a cronjob running every 2 hours a script containing a few rsync job to sync my pc to my homeserver. Most lines look like this one (some have `--exclude` arguments):

`rsync -e ssh -a --delete --log-file={LOG_FILE} {LOCAL_DIR}/src/ {REMOTE_SERVER}:{REMOTE_DIR}/dest/"`

I would like to save on the destination machine a copy of deleted/changed files, in case I mess up something in my computer and don't realize it before a scheduled rsync job.

I tried using `--backup` but couldn't get it to work.

Is there a way to do what I am wanting to do or should I do it some other way?

Comment: Another option is `rsnapshot` which will give you GFS backups

Comment: @roaima I must have done something wrong before, got it working now with `--backup`

Comment: That's great. I'm pleased for you. Ideally, you'll move your "I got it working" into an answer (i.e. not in your question), and then accept your own answer. You'll get points for that and I'll +1 you too.

Comment: Consider also using a revision control tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working now with this command template:

```
rsync -e ssh -a --delete --backup --backup-dir=.rsync_recycle/{TIME_STRING} --exclude=.rsync_recycle --log-file={LOG_FILE} {LOCAL_DIR}/src/ {REMOTE_SERVER}:{REMOTE_DIR}/dest/"
```